# Disable https in toran proxy config

Tags: https, toran-proxy

I was trying to add an private repository which is channeled by http (not https) in toran proxy. However, if I add this repository, toran comes up with this message:

[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] Your configuration does not allow connections to http://foo.bar.de/scm/hp/foo-wp-theme.git. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#secure-http for details.

I'm whondering where to change the config, so that http-channels are allowed.

Any help would be nicefull.

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its handled in app/toran/composer/config.json:

```
{
    "config": {
        "secure-http" : false
    }
}
```